# Given $p,q$ with $p>1,q\ge\frac1 p$, can I find $c>0$ s.t. $pqa^{pq}\ge ca^q$ for all $a\in(0,1]$?

Tags: calculus, inequality, exponentiation

Let $p>1$ and $q\ge\frac1p$. Can I show that there is a $c>0$ s.t. $pqa^{pq}\ge ca^q$ for all $a\in (0,1]$?

Clearly, for all $r\ge0$, it holds $a^r\in(0,1]$. And for all $r\ge1$, it holds $a^r\le a$. So, I obtain $a^{pq}\le a^q$. But that's not helpful.

Comment: I would solve this problem as founding a positive lower bound for $\frac{pqa^{pq}}{a^q}$, and as $a\in (0, 1]$, it has a lower bound...

Comment: Is there a symbol like $\gt \geq$?

Comment: Please take ownership of the questions you post, by explicitely telling us what *you* were assigned to do;  do not imply that we here need to do anything.  Hence, better to say: I'm stuck here, or "I need to figure out...".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$pqa^{pq} \geq ca^q \Leftrightarrow a^{(p-1)q}\geq c/(pq)$. Now let $a \rightarrow 0$…

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: What happens to the LHS as $a \rightarrow 0$? And the RHS?

Comment: The lhs tends to $0$. And nothing happens to the rhs. Sorry, don't get what you're trying to hint me to.

Comment: The LHS is zero, and the RHS is a positive constant, yes. So?

Comment: Yes, okay. I was confused by something in my real application which is not transparent in the question I posted here. We simply need to take $c$ to be the infimum of $pqa^{(p-1)q}$ over all the $a$'s we are interested in. But there won't be a common $c$ over the whole set $(0,1]$ as I posted here.